# Replace whitespaces with "-" for a channel name discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Im using a basic command to create a channel. The issue is that when I provide a channel name with whitespaces for example: hello its me, the bot creates a channel named hello. How can I fix this?
Here's the command I have tried:

```
@bot.command()
async def create(ctx, name):
 guild = ctx.message.guild
 newname=name.replace(" ", "-")
 await guild.create_text_channel(newname)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably just an issue with how you are calling the command. `discord.py` separates positional arguments by space, so if you type the command `!create hello its me`, the **create** command is called and **hello** is passed as the `name` argument. To negate this feature of separating positional arguments, just wrap the text you're passing with single or double quotes.

So, instead of:

`!create hello its me`

you would call the command with:

`!create "hello its me"`